# Как сделать что бы img выходило за контейнер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

[image]

Сделал через absolute, но как правильно тогда расположить блок с текстом? Может есть какие то ещё способы?

Comment: Правильно расположить блок с текстом - это как? вопрос сформулирован неточно.

Comment: Если сделать img через absolute то как правильно спозиционировать блок с текстом. Что здесь не понятного?

Comment: Во-первых, предоставьте код, во-вторых, если absolute применяется только к img, то с текстом работаем, как обычно.

Comment: Код: https://codepen.io/Anton-forntend/pen/bMemLY.  Да absolute только к img. Но тогда блок с текстом 'не видит' img и залазит под него. Я и хочу узнать как правильно позиционировать блок с текстом, что бы было так как на макете и проблем с адаптивом меньше было.

Comment: @ГришаТкачёв, позиционировать блоки можно разными способами, среди них нет "правильных" и "неправильных" - все зависит от ситуации, разметки, целевых браузеров, знания CSS.

Comment: @ГришаТкачёв, Абсолютное позиционирование одного элемента означает необходимость абс./фикс. позиционирования соседей (если исключить вариант маржинов - что тоже "правильно", но попутно создает несколько сложностей). Вы это осознаете?

Comment: Я это понимаю. И знаю, что нет правильных и неправильных способов позиционирования. Напишите пожалуйста так, как вы бы сверстали эту секцию.

Answer (score 1):

Я понял. Чтобы текст стал поверх картинки, которой задано position: relative, нужно тексту также задать аналогичное позиционирование с z-index. См. пример.

```css
main-offer {
 background: #F0EFEE;
}

.main-offer .container {
 position: relative;
 height: 600px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.main-offer__icon img {
 display: block;
 z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: -390px;
  top: -75px;
}

.share-price {
 font-size: 1.875rem;
 color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 90px;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'TruenoUltBlk';
 color: white;
 font-size:  4.375rem;
    position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 190px;
}

.variant {
 font-family: 'TruenoUltBlk';
 color: #ff7373;
 font-size: 3.125rem;
}

.main-offer__text-descr {
 color: #8a8784;
 line-height: 26px;
}

.main-offer__text-btn {
 font-family: 'TruenoBd';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #FF7270;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-offer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="main-offer__icon">
    <img src="http://www.clipartsuggest.com/images/379/running-shoes-clip-art-png-qxijnB-clipart.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="main-offer__text">
    <span class="share-price">From $80.00</span>
    <h1>Nike Air Max</h1>
    <div class="variant">50 Variants</div>
    <p class="main-offer__text-descr">Since this is our favorite sneaker, we’re bringing you <br>
    50 variants to suit everyone’s needs.</p>
    <a href="#" class="main-offer__text-btn">BROWSE VARIANTS</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Нет мне нужно так как на макете. Слева элемент с absolute(img), справа блок с текстом. Я прошу вас написать так как вы бы сверстали эту секцию, посмотрите на макет и просто напишите пожалуйста как это сверстать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так. Принцип поймёте - все остальное сами сделаете. Только на всю страницу разворачивайте. Адаптивность и pixel-to-pixel сами доделаете.

```css
main-offer {
 background: #F0EFEE;
}

.main-offer .container {
 position: relative;
 height: 600px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;

}

.main-offer__icon {
 display: block;
 z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: -390px;
  top: -75px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
}
.main-offer__text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 30px;
}
.share-price {
 font-size: 1.875rem;
 color: #623232;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'TruenoUltBlk';
 color: #623232;
 font-size:  4.375rem;
}

.variant {
 font-family: 'TruenoUltBlk';
 color: #ff7373;
 font-size: 3.125rem;
}

.main-offer__text-descr {
 color: #8a8784;
 line-height: 26px;
}

.main-offer__text-btn {
 font-family: 'TruenoBd';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #FF7270;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-offer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="main-offer__icon">
    <img src="http://www.clipartsuggest.com/images/379/running-shoes-clip-art-png-qxijnB-clipart.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="main-offer__text">
    <span class="share-price">From $80.00</span>
    <h1>Nike Air Max</h1>
    <div class="variant">50 Variants</div>
    <p class="main-offer__text-descr">Since this is our favorite sneaker, we’re bringing you <br>
    50 variants to suit everyone’s needs.</p>
    <a href="#" class="main-offer__text-btn">BROWSE VARIANTS</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!